# UIKit - How to prevent default blur and focus background of UITextField?

Tags: swift, uikit, tvos

As you can see in the image, the `UITextField` (only on `tvOS`?) by default has these behaviors:

- A translucent overlay (make the background and the white text grey in the second button)
- A white background and bigger size when it's focused (the first button)

[image: example of button default behaviors]

**How do I remove/change these behaviors?**

### What did I do?

- I tried to change all color related property (except text color) in Interface Builder to `Clear color`

[image: view configs]

- I used these code to build the view programmatically

  ```
    let view = UITextField()

    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.font = view.font?.withSize(16)
    view.textAlignment = .center
    view.borderStyle = .none
    view.tintColor = .clear
    view.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
    view.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
    view.textColor = .white
    view.disabledBackground = .none
    view.background = .none
    view.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(gray: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    view.layer.shadowColor = CGColor(gray: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    view.layer.borderColor = CGColor(gray: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
  ```

### Additional Information

- A new tvOS app project, created with XCode 12.2 in macOS 10.15.7
- Run on Apple TV simulator
- No additional libraries/pods used

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we always can inherit UIKit classes and do whatever layout/style we want. Here is very raw demo of how this can be done.

Prepared & tested with Xcode 12.1 / tvOS 14.0

[image: demo2]

[image: demo3]

So just substitute custom subclass of UITextField class

[image: demo1]

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    lazy var textLayer = CATextLayer()
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        textLayer.font = self.font
        textLayer.fontSize = 36
        textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
        textLayer.frame = layer.bounds
        layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
        layer.borderWidth = 2
    }

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        layer.borderColor = self.isFocused ? UIColor.black.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
        textLayer.frame = layer.bounds
        textLayer.string = self.text?.isEmpty ?? true ? self.placeholder : self.text
    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        // blocks standard styling
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I came from web dev so I couldn't wrap myself around this yet. I will mark this answer and award the bounty in 14hrs.
As a side question, can you point to me some tutorials about in-depth features like this? The existing tutorial only tackle the surface.